How to Implement a Minimum Funding Requirement in a Solidity Smart Contract?
I'm currently developing a Solidity smart contract named FundMe, where users can contribute funds in Ether (ETH). I'm aiming to enforce a minimum funding requirement of $50 USD equivalent. However, I'm encountering issues with the implementation, particularly with the conversion rate calculation and the enforcement of the minimum value.
Here's the relevant portion of my contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts@1.1.0/src/v0.8/shared/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {
    uint public minimumUsd = 50 * 1e18;
    
    function fund() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "No Value Sent");
        require(msg.value >= minimumUsd, "Didn't Send Enough");

        // Further contract logic...
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns(uint) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
        (,int256 price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint(price * 1e10);
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint ethAmount) public view returns(uint) {
        uint ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1e18;

        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

    // Withdraw function implementation omitted for brevity
}


However, when I attempt to send a transaction with an amount of 0.02 ETH, which according to my calculations equals approximately $57.72, I receive the error message "Didn't Send Enough". Similarly, when inspecting the minimumUsd variable using a function call, it displays a value of 50 ETH equivalent to $143,875.00, which seems incorrect.
Could someone please assist me in correcting the conversion rate calculation and ensuring that the minimum funding requirement is accurately enforced in USD? Additionally, any guidance on how to correctly set the minimum value to $50 USD equivalent would be greatly appreciated.


1 ether is equivalent to 1e18 wei.
50 * 1e18 

sets minimumUsd to represent 50 ether.
If you want to set 50 dollars on solidity contract.
int priceInUSD = getThePrice() / 10 ** 8; //1 ether in USD 

Or, you can deploy the contract through code and before deploying the contract, you could fetch the current parity through coingecko and pass it to the contract as variable. for this, you have to implement constuctor. For example in solidity code:
constructor(uint minimum) {
    // msg.sender who is attempting to create the contract
    // in case you need to implement owneship
    manager = msg.sender;
    minimumContribution = minimum;
}

in javascript side:
const URL = signUpForURL

const fetcher = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const json = await res.json();

  return json.market_data.current_price.usd ?? null;
};

you calculate the minimum amount, this will make your contract more reusable, because maybe someone else wants to set 100 dollars as min. When you deploy the contract, you pass the minimum amount to deploy code
